# How to fix error of android studio in java2smali

Tags: java, android, android-studio, smali

i want to convert my java file to smali file

and i using java2smali plugin

but when i want to compile to smali, i get this error :

```
   Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.computeModuleDatas(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:1276)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1246)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:995)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:719)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:371)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


enter code here
```

- i added android-gradle to my project but error not fixed!!!!!

Comment: Did you upgrade your android studio?

Comment: yes, that is latest version

Comment: and before upgrading was it working fine?